# Autoplay videos which location retrieved from database

Tags: javascript, php, autoplay

I asked by someone to make a simple dashboard that show profiles video. The location of the videos is save in database, so i need to retrieve it first.
That's my code in `index.php`

```
<body onload="onload();">
    <video style="border: 5px solid black" controls="" id="video" width="720" height="480" onended="onVideoEnded();">
    </video>
    <script>
        var vid_list = [];
        var list_index = 0;
        var video_player = null;
        function onload(){
            console.log("body loaded");
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "get_location.php", true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    vid_list = [];
                    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                        vid_list.push(data[i].lokasi);
                        console.log(vid_list[i]); //running
                    }
                }
            }
            for(var x = 0; x < vid_list.length; x++){
                console.log(vid_list[x]);
            }
            video_player = document.getElementById("video");
            video_player.setAttribute("src", vid_list[list_index]);
            video_player.play();
        }

        function onVideoEnded(){
            //console.log("video ended");
            if(list_index < vid_list.length - 1){
                list_index++;
            }
            else{
                list_index = 0;
            }
            video_player.setAttribute("src", vid_list[list_index]);
            video_player.play();
        }
</script>
</body>
```

and this is `get_location.php`

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","video");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM video";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $data = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

The problem is the video cannot be played, in the video screen i get message

> Video Format or MIME type is not supported

and in browser console, a got this error message :

> HTTP load failed with status 404. Load of media resource `http://localhost/video_autoplay/undefined failed.`

But when i try to call a value like  `vid_list[1];` in the console, the value is exist, thats mean `readyState = 4` and `state = 200`

can somebody help me ?

Comment: Paste the console.log of vid_list here. I need to see the parameters you use.
the "undefined" text is a very big clue

Comment: "video_player.setAttribute("src", vid_list[list_index]);" this would be "http://localhost/video_autoplay/undefined" if your script sits at http://localhost/video_autoplay/ and you call an array index out of bounds.
add console.log("Playing " + list_index) at the onEnded call

Comment: Array [ "videos/Naruto short clip [AMV] - YouTube.MP4", "videos/Naruto Short clip Amv - YouTube - Copy.MP4", "videos/Mother And Son (Kushina And Naruto) (Short Video) - YouTube.MP4" ]

Comment: that was the result of console.log(vid_list) @DannyZB

Comment: when i add `else` after readyState condition like this :

`if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
          vid_list = [];
          for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
           vid_list.push(data[i].lokasi);
           console.log(vid_list[i]);//running
          }
      }
      else{
       console.log("failed");
      }`

the `console.log("failed");` is running

Comment: and the idm download button is appear above the video player, and i can download it, but why the video cannot be play ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done, I change the code to :

```
<body>
    <video style="border: 5px solid black" controls="" id="video" width="720" height="480" onended="onVideoEnded();">
    </video>
</body>
    <script>
        var vid_list = [];
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "get_location.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                vid_list = [];
                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                    vid_list.push(data[i].lokasi);
                    console.log(vid_list[i]);//running
                }
                testing(vid_list);
            }
        }
        //console.log(vid_list);
        var list_index = 0;
        var video_player = null;
        function testing(param){
            console.log(param);
            // console.log("body loaded");
            video_player = document.getElementById("video");
            video_player.setAttribute("src", param[list_index]);
            console.log(list_index);
            console.log(param);
            video_player.play();
            video_player.volume = 0.30;
        }

        function onVideoEnded(){
            //console.log("video ended");
            if(list_index < vid_list.length - 1){
                list_index++;
            }
            else{
                list_index = 0;
            }
            video_player.setAttribute("src", vid_list[list_index]);
            video_player.play();
        }
        //document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = vid_list[2];
</script>
```